# psycopg2 sql.SQL how to implement timestamp > now() - INTERVAL '8 days'?

Tags: psycopg2

I want to select records newer than 8 days from several tables. This is not working:

```
self._getRawData = sql.SQL("SELECT * FROM {} WRERE {} > NOW() - INTERVAL {}")
...
cur = self._conn.cursor()
cur.execute(self._getRawData.format(sql.Identifier('MyTS.MyTable'), \
                                    sql.Identifier('Timestamp'), \
                                    sql.Identifier('8 days')))
```

gives error:

```
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near ""Timestamp""
```

Below is working OK, but I want to implement sql.SQL for several tables. Any advice?

```
statement = "SELECT * FROM \"MyTS\".\"MyTable\" WHERE \"Timestamp\" > NOW() - INTERVAL                 \'8 days\'"
cur = self._conn.cursor()
cur.execute(statement)
```

**Update:** Thanks to the comments, I solved it with

```
self._getRawData = sql.SQL("SELECT * FROM {}.{} WHERE {} > NOW() - INTERVAL {}")
...
sql.Literal('8 days')))
```

Comment: Have you tried with `WHERE` instead of the incorrectly spelled `WRERE`?

Comment: Also  this `sql.Identifier('8 days')` needs to be `sql.Literal('8 days')`. The string is not a SQL identifier(table, column, function,etc name) it is a literal value used by `INTERVAL`.

Comment: Thanks 4 the advice about Literal! WHERE was typed whongly by me here, but Literal was useful indeed. Also, ir's needed to seperate schema and table name, like this self._getRawData = sql.SQL("SELECT * FROM {}.{} WHERE {} > NOW() - INTERVAL {}")